# Modal not displayed when clicking a navbar link

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently trying to implement a modal that would show up when clicking a link in a navbar. I'm aware that similar questions have already been asked, but none of the solutions could work.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Tool</a>
</div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add Something</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</nav>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
 <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Scripts I'm using are : bootstrap.js, bootstrap.min.js, jquery-2.1.4.min.js
P.S : I've already tried the href="#" in the link.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Importing your code into JSfiddle and linking the libraries appears to work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/qs7ea5zu/ . You mentioned you're using both the .js and .min.js boostrap files, you should only be using one of these at a time. Does your browser console describe any errors on page load or button activation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
(I only inserted the correct dependencies, your code is working)

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Tool</a>
</div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add Something</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</nav>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
 <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```